# How did Eloise Hawking know which flight the losties had to catch?

Tags: plot-explanation, lost

In Lost TV series, Daniel Faraday's mother (Eloise Hawking) meets the losties who want to return to the island.

***How*** does she know what flight they have to catch to crash again and return. What's the point? Is there another island's rule that put her in charge of doing this? Or it's just a scientific way to make them "let go" the reality they're attached to?

***Why*** instead, Faraday's father (Widmore) has to put so much effort to find this island?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [**the article about the flight on lostpedia**](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Ajira_Flight_316)

> She said that windows provide a route back, but they didn't stay open long, and the window through which they were supposed to enter closed in 36 hours. She handed Jack a binder that contained all air routes that flew over the coordinates of the Island, pointing out that the intended window was directly in the flight path of Ajira Airways Flight 316. Ms. Hawking emphasized that they must take that flight if they had any hope of returning to the Island.

Essentially, the island is constantly moving and shifting around (which is what makes it so elusive).  In order to get the Oceanic 6 back to the island, they needed a flight who's path would match up perfectly with where the island would be so that they can crash it onto the island to return.

There is no island rule about this having to be the flight but merely the only way to keep the island "stable" enough to *save* it is to have the original/remaining candidates back onto the island in order to stop it from producing the time flashes so sporadically.

Eloise is merely the one that runs **The Lamp Post** station which it's purpose is to detect **where** the island currently resides and where it will be.

Faraday's father, Widmore turns out to be the original "others" leader back in the 1950s.  And since Ben banished him when he came of age, he's been desperately trying to get back to the island ever since.  I'm sure anyone ejected from their longtime home that is constantly moving around the world would be pretty determined to get back at any cost.

Comment: Ok, it's all clear. Wildmore didn't know how to get back to the island because he just had no idea about the existence of this Lamp post. Back in the 1950s also Eloise was one of the "others"; my doubt now is, how could Eloise get control of this church whe it's clear it was a **Dharma Initiative** building. The others put her in charge when there was no Dharma's employee left so they could have free access to everything?

Comment: Without going into too much detail, it might be best for you to re-watch most, if not all of season 5 as these questions are easily answered by someone who has seen them.  However, if you'd like to ask another question on the site, I'd be happy to answer there, rather than comments.

Comment: More importantly than stopping the time skips, the candidates need to get there to take over from Jacob and protect the Heart.

Answer (score 2):

Another part of it was also "re-creating" the conditions of Oceanic 815.  But it had everything to do with the Lamp Post being a place that find the limited window of opportunity to get back to the island.